# Guided Visual Flow

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow, visual

I am looking to build out a guided flow for some of my users for when they are out on site performing a Survey.
I have a site survey object built that is comprehensive and captures all the information we need, but looks a bit boring as it is a simple page layout.

What i'd like to do is have our users click a button which kicks off a flow that guides them through all the measurements they need to capture (Residential Gates), Ideally moving around an image and showing them what it is they need to capture.

[image: gate sample]

So the users are guide through each data point they need to capture, and once completed, it saves and the record is created.
Can this be achieve through native Flow functionality, or can anyone recommend any 3rd Party tools?
I figure if flow can't do it, it could been a Visualforce job, or possibly use a tool like Skuid for build out an enhanced UI.
Love to hear your thoughts on this.
Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Are the residential gate images dynamic? Or will the end users see the same image each time with the same measurement points?

Comment: There are fundamental measurements that all gates will need (width of pier, height of pier to under cap etc). The only dynamic ranges of data occur when selecting style and finishing. Currently these are handled by field dependencies (see image sample link - https://ibb.co/bKqY6Rd)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This can be achieved by creating a **Screen Flow** with **Display Image** and **Number** field components. You can add and name more of these **Number** text boxes as needed or add subsequent screens to denote the type of measurements for all necessary dimensions. On the right panel you can add validation if necessary and then capture and store these values on a Salesforce record.